# Creaty an single array by a Laravel Collection, but with specific fields

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, api, eloquent

I have this Model where I'm calling with

`$data = ProcessoSeletivoRDSincroniza::all();`

This model gaves me a collection with more than 300 records, with attributes like name, celphone, email etc..

And I have to pass this collection to a API body request, by an array, this array has specific key fields, and the only way that I think about doing this its iterating this collection with a foreach loop, and creating/setting this array with this collection fields, and works ok, but my application does one request for every record, and this is not a good way to handle it.

So I'm thinking if's there a way to create an "custom" and single array with all that records, so I dont need to iterate and make a request by record, and just tranform all this records in a JSON file and send it.

This is my code now:

```
        $data = ProcessoSeletivoRDSincroniza::all();
        //$data = $data->toArray();

        $api = new RDStationApi();
        foreach($data as $row)
        {
            $events = array(
                "event_type" => "CONVERSION",
                "event_family" => "CDP",
                "payload" => [
                    "conversion_identifier" => "Name of the conversion event",
                    "name" => $row->nome_completo,
                    "email" => $row->email,
                    "personal_phone" => $row->telefone,
                    "cf_ps_curso" => $row->ps_curso,
                    "cf_ps_ano_semestre" => $row->ps_anosemestre,
                    "cf_ps_data_vestibular_agendado" => $row->ps_data_vestibular_agendado,
                    "cf_ps_nota_enem" => (string) $row->ps_nota_enem,
                    "cf_forma_ingresso" => $row->ps_forma_ingresso, 
                    "cf_ps_unidade" => $row->ps_unidade, 
                    "cf_ps_situacao" => $row->ps_situacao
                ]
                );
                $return = $api->update_contact($events);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Laravel functionality called `API-Resources`.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources

Create a new `Resource` for your Model:

```
php artisan make:resource ProcessoSeletivoRDSincronizaResource
```

Afterwards this will create a file in the Resource folder named; `ProcessoSeletivoRDSincronizaResource` , in this file you will need to adapt the `toArray()` method.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class ProcessoSeletivoRDSincronizaResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            //ADD ALL THE FIELDS, methods also work normally: $this->myMethod()
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        ];
    }
}
```

Afterwards you can use the Resource like this:

```
//for the whole collection
 $events = ProcessoSeletivoRDSincronizaResource::collection(ProcessoSeletivoRDSincroniza::all());
//or for single use
 $event = new ProcessoSeletivoRDSincronizaResource($single_model)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Thank you